# How can I add an iOS icon using PhoneGap 3.5?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

Ok...so, I have been reading a lot about this and banging my head for a while.

If I run "phonegap run ios" in my terminal...then I get a lovely icon in the simulator, everything seems to work fine.

However, if I use phonegap build and pull my latest from github...then use the QR code to install it on my phone, then I get no icon at all. The app works...just no icon.

Below is my config file...and all of the images are actually in the paths. I know I am just missing something here, but I am not sure what.

Help!

Thanks,
David

```
<icon src="www/icon.png" />

<!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
<!-- iOS 6.1 -->
<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-57@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-29.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-29@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="www/res/ios/Icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />
```

**Update Solved!**

Ok, so the answer down there, along with some other stuff I have seen, showed me that the times that people have been successful with PG Build is when they don't use that res directory...they all seem to use something else. I dunno why.

In my case I just copied all of my icons into the img directory...so instead of:

```
www/res/ios/Icon-60.png
```

I am using:

```
img/ios/Icon-60.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine , may be **path** has some issues.

Check below how i set the **path** and try accordingly. They work fine for me on PhoneGap build.

At the root where **index.html** file is, there is an **img** folder which contains all these images.

```
<!-- Icons for IOS -->
    <icon gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" src="img/iosIcons/icon-57.png"  />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" src="img/iosIcons/icon-72.png"  />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="114" src="img/iosIcons/icon-57-2x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" src="img/iosIcons/icon-72-2x.png"  /> 

<!-- Splash for IOS --> 
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" src="img/splash.png"/>  
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" src="img/splash@2x.png"/>   
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" src="images/phone/1x/bglangscreen.png" />
```